# How to fix "InternalError: Missing 0-th output from node" in tf.tensor_scatter_add

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using TensorFlow (v. 1.13.1), an algorithm chooses a random column of a [nxm] matrix to which to add a vector using tf.tensor_scatter_add.  If m>1, then the algorithm works.  In graph mode, if m=1, then I get an InternalError.  In eager mode, all works as expected.  Is this a bug in Tensorflow?

The code below is a fragment from the (Markov jump process) algorithm which demonstrates the error. `Foo.update_state` draws an `event` at random given (n-1)*m potential events with rate `rates`.  The `event_type` and `id` are calculated from the event and used to select a) a row of `Foo.stoichiometry`, and b) a column of `state`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stoichiometry = tf.constant([[-1, 1, 0, ], [0, -1, 1, ], [0, 0, 0]])

    def update_state(self, rates, state):
        event = tf.squeeze(tf.random.categorical([rates], 1, dtype=tf.int32, name='drawEvent'))
        event_type = tf.squeeze(event // state.shape[1], name='packEvent_type')
        id = tf.squeeze(event % state.shape[1], name='packId')
        indices = tf.stack((tf.range(state.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32),
                            tf.broadcast_to(id, [state.shape[0]])), axis=1, name='indices')
        stoic = self.stoichiometry[event_type]
        return tf.tensor_scatter_add(state, indices, stoic, name='updateStates')
```

In graph mode, if `Foo.update_state` is called with `state` a [n, m] matrix with m>1, then the algorithm works:

```py
rates = tf.constant([-1.2, -np.inf, -np.inf -np.inf]) # Ensure event_type=0, id=0
state = tf.constant([[999, 999],
                     [  1,   1],
                     [  0,   0]])
epi = Foo()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(epi.update_state(rates, state))
print(res)
[[998 999]
 [  2   1]
 [  0   0]]
```

However, with m=1, I get an error:

```py
rates = tf.constant([-1.2, -np.inf]) # Ensure event_type=0, id=0
state = tf.constant([[999],
                     [  1],
                     [  0]])
epi = Foo()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(epi.update_state(rates, state))
print(res)
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Missing 0-th output from node updateStates (defined at /Users/cpjewell/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/scratch_1.py:16)
```

If in eager mode, this error does not occur, and I get my expected output (which is [[998], [2], [0]]).

This feels like a TF bug, but wanted to check I'm not missing anything before I file it as such.

System spec:

- OSX 10.14.4
- Anaconda Python 3.6.6
- TensorFlow 1.13.1.

Comment: Any further observations on this? I am facing a similar issue.